# A trouble about the Simons’ inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have a trouble in the proof to  Simons’ inequality:

About prove that:

$\displaystyle \inf_{x \,\in\, C_1} \sup_{B} (x) \le \sup_{B} (\lim_{n} \sup (x_n)) \Longrightarrow  \sup_{B} (\lim_{n} \sup (x_n)) \ge \inf \{\sup_{B} (x) \,; x \,\in\, \text{conv}\{x_n\}\} $

$\text{conv}$: convex hull

Any hints would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What about that boxed statement are you struggling with?

Comment: I have a trouble to show that $\displaystyle \inf_{x \,\in\, C_1} \sup_{B} (x) \le \sup_{B} (\lim_{n} \sup (x_n)) \Longrightarrow  \sup_{B} (\lim_{n} \sup (x_n)) \ge \inf \{\sup_{B} (x) \,; x \,\in\, \text{conv}\{x_n\}\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

$\displaystyle  \text{conv}\{x_n\}\subset C_1\subset \overline{\text{conv}}\{x_n\}\Longrightarrow \inf \{\sup_{B} (x) \,; x \,\in\, \text{conv}\{x_n\}\}=\inf_{x \,\in\, C_1} \sup_{B} (x)$